# Django on Heroku dumpdata incomplete output

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-cms

I've been trying to dump a relatively small amount of data (80 rows or so of `django-cms text plugin`<sup>1</sup>) remotely via Heroku toolbelt:

```
heroku run python manage.py dumpdata text
```

But I get random incomplete output <del>that gets closer to EOF every run</del> (presumably cached?).

```
11:09 PM $> heroku run python manage.py dumpdata text | wc -c
108351
11:09 PM $> !!
120629
11:09 PM $> !!
122693
11:10 PM $> !!
122949
11:10 PM $> !!
153419
11:13 PM $> !!
120877
```

Anyone run into something similar? I'm using *Django 1.4* with *postgresql*.

*<sup>1</sup> although, it is blobs of HTML o_0*: [see docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.2/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#text).

**Edit:** assume this is just a limitation?? pg_dump's/ restore was my "backup" plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like for some reason the script times out.  This is either a bug or a "feature" on Heroku's part.  Here is a workaround:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 5):

Yet another workaround is to add a sleep command to stop the session timing out.

heroku run "python manage.py dumpdata; sleep 10"

Presumably the number grows along with your database...

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler workaround is to run dumpdata from within a heroku bash prompt:

```
heroku run bash

python manage.py dumpdata ...
```

Then capture the output from your terminal. Copy and paste worked for me. I'm sure there's a fancier way to do this.